# Problem with react transition group when transit modal

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-transition-group

I try to animated my modal by using multiple method, but none seem working properly.
For example, i try to add transition in .modalBackground but it's not working.

```
.modalBackground {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.modalBackground:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

After that, I use a lib call react-transition-group to animated the modal but those transition is not working. The modal appear without click the button and none of animation work
Here is my code for running transition

```
import { useState } from "react"
import Modal from "./OTPCode";
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group';
export default function Table() {
    const defaultStyles = {
        transition: `opacity 300ms ease-in-out`,
        opacity: 0,
    };

    const transitionStyles = {
        entering: { opacity: 1 },
        entered: { opacity: 1 },
        exiting: { opacity: 0 },
        exited: { opacity: 0 },
    };
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
 const handleUploadOTP = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    }
return (<><button className="openModalBtn" onClick={handleUploadOTP}>
                                Upload
                            </button>
                            <Transition in={openModal} timeout={300}>
                                {state => (
                                    <Modal
                                        title="Transition alert"
                                        styles={{
                                            ...defaultStyles,
                                            ...transitionStyles[state]
                                        }}
                                        closeModal={setOpenModal} />
                                )}
                            </Transition> </>);
}
```

Here is my OTPCode

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import configData from "./../conf.json";
import axios from 'axios';
import './../Ultility/styles.css'

function Modal({ closeModal }) {

    const [otp, setOtp] = useState(new Array(6).fill(""));
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState();
    const [isSuccess, setIsSuccess] = useState();
    const [argentHost, setArgentHost] = useState("");
    const [crontab, setCrontab] = useState("");
    const [times, setTimes] = useState("");
    const Uploaddiv = document.getElementById('Upload');
    const OTPdiv = document.getElementById('OTP');
    const StatusOTP = document.getElementById('StatusOTP');
    const StatusUpload = document.getElementById('StatusUpload');
    const Uploadbtn = document.getElementById('UploadBtn');

    const handleOTPChange = (element, index) => {
        if (isNaN(element.value)) {
            console.log(element.value);
            return false;
        }

        setOtp([...otp.map((d, idx) => (idx === index) ? element.value : d)])

        //Focus next input
        if (element.nextSibling) {
            element.nextSibling.focus();
        }
    }

    const handleBackSpace = (element, index) => {
        if (element.key === 'Backspace' && element.target.value !== '') { element.target.value = '' } else if (element.key === 'Backspace' && index !== 0) {
            setOtp([...otp.map((d, idx) => (idx === index - 1 || idx === index) ? '' : d)])
            element.target.previousSibling.select();
        }

    }

    const sendOTPVerify = (OTPcode) => {
        console.log(OTPcode);
        axios.post(`${configData.SERVER_URL}/otp/verify`, {
            session_id: localStorage.getItem('sessionId'),
            otp_code: OTPcode,
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    OTPdiv.style.display = "none";
                    Uploaddiv.style.display = "inline";
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error, "error");
                if (error.response.status === 403) {
                    StatusOTP.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
    }

    const handleFileChange = (event) => {

        if (event.target.files[0].type === 'text/x-sh' || event.target.files[0].type === 'text/x-python') {
            event.target.files[0].status = 'File is ready to upload';
            Uploadbtn.style.display = 'flex'
        } else {
            event.target.files[0].status = 'Please select a Bash or Python file type to upload';
            Uploadbtn.style.display = 'none'
        }
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0])

    };
    const handleUploadSend = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        if (selectedFile) {
            formData.append("file", selectedFile);
        } else { console.log("there is no such file!") }

        axios.post(`${configData.SERVER_URL}/upload/?agent_host=${argentHost}&crontab=${crontab}&times=${times}&sid=` + localStorage.getItem('sessionId') + ``, formData, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": selectedFile.type,
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    window.location.reload(false);
                } else if (response.status === 403) {
                    setIsSuccess(response.data.detail);
                    console.log(response);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error, "error");
                if (error.response.status === 403) {
                    StatusUpload.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });
    };
    return (
        <div className="modalBackground modal1">
            <div className="modalContainer CT1">
                <div className='titleCloseBtn'>
                    <button onClick={() => closeModal(false)}> X </button></div>
                <div className='OTP' id='OTP'>
                    <div className="titleModal">
                        <h1>Enter your OTP to Continues Upload</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="bodyModal">
                        <div className='row'>
                            {otp.map((data, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <input
                                        className="otp-field"
                                        type="text"
                                        name="otp"
                                        maxLength="1"
                                        key={index}
                                        value={data}
                                        onChange={e => handleOTPChange(e.target, index)}
                                        onKeyDown={e => handleBackSpace(e, index)}
                                        onFocus={e => e.target.select()}></input>
                                )
                            })}
                            <p>OTP code Entered: {otp.join("")}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footerModal OTPBtn">
                        <button onClick={() => setOtp([...otp.map(v => "")])}> Clear</button>
                        <button onClick={() => sendOTPVerify(otp.join(""))}> Continues</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="StatusLogin Status2" id="StatusOTP"> <p className="statuslogin">Incorrect OTP entered</p></div>

                <div  >
                    <div className='Upload' id='Upload'>
                        <div className="titleModal">
                            <h1>Please select a file to upload</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className='bodyModal'>
                            <div className='row'>
                                <div>
                                    <input className='choosename' type="file" style={{ color: "transparent", width: "160px" }} onChange={handleFileChange} />
                                    <label className='userLabel' htmlFor="argenthost" value="Argent Host" />
                                    <input className='userInput' type="argenthost" placeholder="Argent Host" id="argenthost" onChange={(e) => setCrontab(e.target.value)} />

                                    <label className='userLabel' htmlFor="crontab" value="Crontab" />
                                    <input className='userInput' type="crontab" placeholder="Crontab" id="crontab" onChange={(e) => setArgentHost(e.target.value)} />

                                    <label className='userLabel' htmlFor="times" value='Times' />
                                    <input className='userInput' type="times" placeholder="Times" id="times" onChange={(e) => setTimes(e.target.value)} />
                                </div>
                                {selectedFile ? (
                                    <div>
                                        <p>Filename: {selectedFile.name}</p>
                                        <p>Status: {selectedFile.status}</p>
                                    </div>
                                ) : (
                                    <p>Select a python or bash file to continues</p>
                                )}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="footerModal UploadBtn" id='UploadBtn'>
                        <button onClick={handleUploadSend}>Upload</button>
                    </div>
                    {isSuccess ? (
                        <div>
                            <p>{isSuccess}</p>
                        </div>
                    ) : (<></>)}
                </div>
                <div className="StatusLogin Status2" id="StatusUpload"> <p className="statuslogin">File with the same name already existed</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Modal
```

And here is my css for OTPCode Modal

```
`.openModalBtn {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-color: transparent;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgb(9, 37, 116);
  color: rgb(253, 250, 57);
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  transition: 0.15s ease;

  &+* {
    margin-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  cursor: pointer;
}
.openModalBtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(253, 250, 57);
  color:rgb(9, 37, 116);
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
.modalBackground {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal1 {
  left: 24%;
  top: 250%;
}

.modal2 {
  left: 22%;
  top: 22%;
}


.modalContainer {
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 25px;
}



.CT1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
}

.CT2 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.modalContainer .titleModal {
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}



.titleCloseBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.titleCloseBtn button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalContainer .bodyModal {
  flex: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.modalContainer .footerModal {
  flex: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.OTPBtn {
  display: flex;
}

.UploadBtn {
  display: none;
}

.modalContainer .footerModal button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.otp-field {
  width: 38px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  height: 40px;
}

.Upload {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type='file'] {
  color: transparent;
}

input::file-selector-button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: none;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

I know it's a mess but please anyone help me with this, i'm very appriciated about that.